# How do I use an android regex to match non-numeric characters in a string?

Tags: android, regex

I’m trying to check if a string contains non-numeric characters.
e.g.: "4012-8888-8888-1881" or "4012 8888 8888 1881"

Here's my code ... it returns false for the above strings.

```
public static boolean containsNonNumericCharacters(String rawInput) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\D+)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(rawInput);
  return m.matches();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `find()` instead of `matches()`

```
return m.find();
```

Answer (score 1):

This tries to match your whole input by the pattern. It would only return `true` if all the characters are non-digits.

You could instead use the pattern `"(\\d+)"` and return `!m.matches()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static boolean containsNonNumericCharacters(String rawInput) {
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(.\\d+)?");
          Matcher m = p.matcher(rawInput);
          return !m.matches();
        }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is trying to match strings of digits, not actual numbers.  The exemplars look like credit card numbers to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceAll` :

```
String result = rawInput.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```